# Fix a command that makes an item give another item?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I used to know a command that would effectively run /give everytime someone was holding a stick. It went something like

```
/execute @a [hasitem={item=stick,location=slot.weapon.mainhand}] run /give @s blaze_rod
```

I could change the items out and whatnot but I tried this command again recently and it would not run the command.

What's wrong with my command?

Comment: Remove the `/` before `give` after `run`. `/` only declares to the chat system that it needs to run the message as a command instead of as a chat message.

Comment: Yeah ik. I just like to put it there regardless

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually figured out an answer earlier today. The correct command is /execute at @a[hasitem={item=stick, location=slot.weapon.mainhand}] run /give @p blaze_rod